# For navigation, should figure titles go inside figcaption?

Tags: image, navigation, semantic-web, semantic-markup, figure

Consider that you land on a category webpage, whose sole purpose it is to direct you to the appropriate sub-category by informing you what's inside each with an image and a short title.

When it comes to [UX considerations — it was suggested](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30099/caption-below-or-above-image-for-navigation-purposes) that the following arrangement would be the most optimal (text before image):

[image]

Each photo and text combination would link to the respective sub-category.

Considering semantic HTML5, since these are titles of sub-categories and not exactly captions, would it be appropriate to use the `<figcaption>` element? Or is something else?

**Using figure captions:**

```
<h2>Our Planet's Animals</h2>
<p>Contrary to popular belief...</p>

<figure>
<a>
<figcaption>Rhinos</figcaption>
<img />
</a>
</figure>
```

**Using headers (or something else) instead:**

```
<h2>Our Planet's Animals</h2>
<p>Contrary to popular belief...</p>

<figure>
<a>
<h3>Rhinos</h3>
<img />
</a>
</figure>
```

Or, what lese would be correct semantically, and allow ease of styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the use of the [`figure` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-figure-element.html#the-figure-element) would not be correct here, as this content is probably the main content of the page, but for `figure` it says:

> […] but that could, without affecting the flow of the document, be moved away from that primary content […]

You'd use `figure` if you have a diagram in a paper or a photograph in a news article etc.: content that "[…] is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document".

Instead, I'd use `section` for each category and enclose all categories in a `nav` (because it is the main navigation *for that sectioning content*, which is opened by the heading "Our Planet's Animals").

```
<h2>Our Planet's Animals</h2>
<p>Contrary to popular belief...</p>

<nav> <!-- nav could be omitted -->

 <section>
  <a>
  <h1>Rhinos</h1> <!-- you could use h3 here instead -->
  <img />
  </a>
 </section>

 <section>
  …
 </section>

 <section>
  …
 </section>

 <section>
  …
 </section>

</nav>
```

---

If you don't want to use headings, one could also use a list for the categories ([`dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element) or `ul`). I think the `ul` fits better than `dl` here:

```
<h2>Our Planet's Animals</h2>
<p>Contrary to popular belief...</p>

<nav> <!-- nav could be omitted -->
 <ul>
  <li><a>Rhinos <img /></a></li>
  <li>…</li>
  <li>…</li>
  <li>…</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

It might also be possible to use `section` in each `li` element (`<li><section>…</section></li>`), but I'm not sure how this would affect the document outline.

Comment: Thanks, good point. However, are you sure section is the right one to use for each?

Comment: @Baumr: If you are using headings, you already create "implicit" sections. Now, if you want to make it explicit, you have the choice between `section`, `article`, `nav` and `aside`. Each category is by no means an own `nav` (it's the container, not each link in the container) and neither an `aside` (as the categories are the primary content). Therefor we'd have the choice between `section` and `article`. It wouldn't be wrong to use `article` here, but I'd only tend to use it if the category would be described in more detail (e. g. an description text *standing on it's own*).

Comment: By that logic, yes, however, also `div` can be considered here. Section carries semantic meaning: http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/ and is reserved for specific cases: http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/ — and I wouldn't say that each image and heading combination has really that much semantic meaning since there's only two elements inside each section. But those are just details really.

Comment: @Baumr: `section` carries no more meaning than what is implied if you use headings without sectioning elements. Semantically, it doesn't make a difference if you use only headings or if you explicitly use `section` elements. If you don't want to use a heading for each category, you don't want to use `section` (but rather a `dl`). `section` only matters for the document outline (while the other sectioning elements `article`, `aside` and `nav` carry *additional* meaning).

Comment: I see. Also, `dl` is a definition list... how would this be a definition list?

Comment: @Baumr: The [definition of `dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element) was changed in HTML5: "an association list consisting of zero or more name-value groups (a description list)". Because the category name and the category image aren't really "separated", a `ul` would probably fit better here. However, I'd still prefer the use of headings (and optionally `section`).